# Best order between stripslashes, utf8_decode, mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string, utf8-decode, stripslashes

What is the best order if I need to use these functions in PHP: stripslashes, utf8_decode and  mysql_real_escape_string.

Actually somme \\ appears for example: Francois\'s Farm.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions at all in new code, so there's really no answer. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: You really don't need any of them. Disable `magic_quotes`, Set mysql database connection to `UTF8` (You also need to set UTF8 encoding for database, table, columns), Use `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`

Answer (score 1):

Easy

- stripslashes have to be applied at the very top of the script, [on the all superglobal arrays, **only** if magic quotes are on](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)
- utf8_decode - never
- mysql_real_escape_string **only for strings** you are going to insert into query, **right before** this insertion.
  In case you're not going to insert any string literals into query - you don't need this function as well.

> Actually somme \ appears for example: Francois\'s Farm.

So, here goes issue #1.
Either turn magic quotes off or run stripslashes as it shown in the link above.